# How to load the page in partials with ajax angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to show the loader for each container which makes ajax call and get the content.

I need to show the loader first in both div columns, and then once the ajax call is success i need to hide the loader for the specific column div whose ajax call is success.

I have tried to do so, but unable to achieve it.

Expected Output:

So on page load the two div's should be filled with the spinner and then once the specific div ajax call is success then the spinner of that particular div should hide, this should repeat for other div as well.

This is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

<!--    <div class="loading-spiner-holder" data-loading><div class="loading-spiner"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" /></div></div>
-->    
    <ul ng-repeat="col in column">
      <li>{{col.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-repeat="col2 in column2">
      <li>{{col2.name}}</li>
    </ul>


  </body>

</html>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JNe1dADae7zCD4QvJtW7?p=preview)

Comment: fairly simple using `ng-if` or `ng-show` or `ng-hide`. Create a wrapper for each column that includes a spinner. WHat is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: @charlietfl, I am unable to add the spinner to the div's, can you please help me with modifying my code. THanks

Comment: whay can't you wrap each `<ul>` and put a spinner inside each? Really doesn't seem complicated

Comment: I thought to do it like that, instead of that I am looking a more generic way, thats the reason I have raised this.

Comment: can create a directive for it...but if you want 2 you need to create 2 somehow and you need somewhere to put them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` will do what you need. BTW you are talking about `DIV` but there is no `DIV` in your `HTML` code.. Here is an example on how you can achieve it without the use of any `Directives`.

```
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
      //define boolean value for your columns : true=show false=hide
      // this will show the spinner on page load
      $scope.ui = {
          showSpinnerCol1 : true,
          showSpinnerCol2 : true
      }
      $scope.column = [];  $scope.column2 = [];
      $http.get('test.json')
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.column = data[0].column;
            $scope.ui.showSpinnerCol1 = false; //hide spinner1 when ajax is done.
        });
        $http.get('test1.json')
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.column2 = data[0].column2;
            $scope.ui.showSpinnerCol2 = false;//hide spinner2 when ajax is done.

        });
  });


<div>
    <div ng-show="ui.showSpinnerCol1" class="loading-spiner">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="col in column">
      <li>{{col.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div>
    <div ng-show="ui.showSpinnerCol2" class="loading-spiner">
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="col2 in column2">
      <li>{{col2.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```